# How to send a GET request to an external API and parse its XML response?

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I need to send a HTTP GET/POST request to an external API which returns XML data and then parse this data. Does an API for this exist in JSP?

If I use that code inside a class and use a method of it in JSP, will there be any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) to send a HTTP request and get the HTTP response as an `InputStream`. You can use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to unmarshal an `InputStream` containing a XML document into a javabean instance which follows the XML structure.

Imagine that the XML response look like this,

```xml
<data>
    <foo>fooValue</foo>
    <bar>barValue</bar>
</data>
```

and your JAXB javabean look like this,

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {

    @XmlElement
    private String foo;

    @XmlElement
    private String bar;

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

then you can unmarshal it something like as follows:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/data.xml").openStream();
Data data = (Data) JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(input);
String foo = data.getFoo(); // fooValue
// ...
```

As with every other line of Java code in JSP, doing this in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class doesn't necessarily cause technical problems, but it may end up in maintenance nightmare.

Comment: thanku. After that how to access a particular element ? data contains unmarshalled content. How to access "username" element form it ?

Comment: Uh, just add a normal javabean getter method to the `Data` class as in the example. Are you familiar with javabeans? Have you bothered to click the JAXB link? It points you to the JAXB tutorial.

Comment: i am newbie. I have checked that manual. But it was hard to understand. So to avoid confusingmyself, i am trying to find a simple and easy to understand tutorial. I do not know much about java bean. Is it creating a class with a property name which is same as the XML element and writing a function to return that variable, that you are talking about ?

Comment: thanku for the example. JAXB javabean is same as a class. Correct ?

Comment: Uh, that's just a Java class, yes. I'd suggest to put this all aside and take some days/weeks to go through a basic Java book/tutorial first to familiarize yourself with the basics of the Java language and terminology.

Comment: thanku. I have already went to a java class. But the coaching was not good. So i am doing this project myself at home by using online tutorials and help from you and others when i have doubts.

Comment: do i have to create properties for all XML elements ? Or only the ones that i needed ?

Comment: Play around with it and find it out yourself :)

Comment: yes. i have to include all! When run with a single property, got a exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"response"). Expected elements are (none)`. I will try adding all elements now. I have only included a getter in the class.

Comment: first line of XML is: `<response function="login_verify" status="ok">`. Next line is: `<result>`. Then inside it all elements are  listed inside it. So how to create attributes for these ?

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214989/how-to-parse-xml-using-jericho-html-parser

Comment: You don't have to include them all. You apparently did something wrong.

Comment: Thank you. But I got it working when above questions solution was used (after making come changes).